# Using Recursive stacks

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I am attempting to implement a random maze generator algorithm in Java. I was able to do it recursively but I have been challenged to do it non-recursively, through the use of stacks. However, I am receiving a runtime error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1... on line 32, and I can not seem to understand the source of this issue.

here is mazedfs.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mazedfs extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
/* default values: */
protected int mh = 41;  // height and width of maze
protected int mw = 51;

protected byte[][] M;   // the array for the maze
public static final int SOUTH = 0;
public static final int EAST = 1;
public static final int NORTH = 2;
public static final int WEST = 3;

protected boolean showvalue = false; // affects drawblock
protected boolean autodelay = true;  // delays automatically between steps

// graphical properties:
protected static int bh = 16;   // height of a graphical block
protected static int bw = 16;   // width of a graphical block
protected int ah, aw;   // height and width of graphical maze
protected int yoff = 80;    // init y-cord of maze
protected Graphics g;
protected int dtime = 40;   // 40 ms delay time
protected Color wallcolor = Color.green;
protected Color pathcolor = Color.black;
protected Color dotcolor = Color.red;


// args determine block size, maze height, and maze width
public mazedfs(int bh0, int mh0, int mw0)
 {
   bh = bw = bh0;  mh = mh0;  mw = mw0;
   ah = bh*mh;
   aw = bw*mw;
   M = new byte[mh][mw];  // initialize maze (all  0's - walls).
   this.setBounds(0,0,aw+10,10+ah+yoff);
   this.setVisible(true);
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch(Exception e) {} // Synch with system
   this.addKeyListener(this);
   g = getGraphics();    //g.setColor(Color.red);
   setup();
 }

public void paint(Graphics g) {} // override automatic repaint

public void setup()
 {
   g.setColor(wallcolor);
   g.fill3DRect(0,yoff,aw,ah,true);  // fill raised rectangle
   g.setColor(pathcolor);
   customize(); // optional startupcode
   //     showStatus("Generating maze...");
   digout(mh-2,mw-2); // start digging!
   // digout exit (if digout complete)
   if (M[mh-2][mw-2]!=0)
   {
       M[mh-1][mw-2] = M[mh-2][mw-1] = 1;
       drawblock(mh-2,mw-1);
   }
   solve();  // this is the function you will write for lab 3, part 1
   trace();  // for part 2
   play();   // for part 3
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int blocksize = bh, mheight = 41, mwidth = 41; // need to be odd
   if (args.length==3)
   {
       mheight=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       mwidth=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       blocksize=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
   }
   mazedfs W = new studentcode(blocksize,mheight,mwidth);
}

public void delay(int ms)
    {
    try {Thread.sleep(ms);} catch(Exception e) {}
    }

public void drawblock(int y, int x)
 {
    g.setColor(pathcolor);
    g.fillRect(x*bw,yoff+(y*bh),bw,bh);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    // following line displays value of M[y][x] in the graphical maze:
    if (showvalue)
      g.drawString(""+M[y][x],(x*bw)+(bw/2-4),yoff+(y*bh)+(bh/2+6));
  }

public void drawdot(int y, int x)
{
    g.setColor(dotcolor);
    g.fillOval(x*bw,yoff+(y*bh),bw,bh);
    if (autodelay) try{Thread.sleep(dtime);} catch(Exception e) {}
}


////// the following functions are to be overriden in subclass:

public void customize()  // user-defined initialization code
{}

/* function to generate random maze */

public void digout(int y, int x)    // override for lab 2
{
     // generates maze
} // digout


/* Write a routine to solve the maze.
   Start at coordinates x=1, y=1, and stop at coordinates
   x=mw-1, y=mh-2.  This coordinate was especially dug out
   after the program called your digout function (in the "actionPerformed"
   method).
*/
public void solve()    // override for lab 3
 {
   int x=1, y=1;
   //      drawdot(y,x);
   // drawblock(y,x) will erase the dot
   // modify this function to move the dot to the end of the maze.  That
   // is, when the dot reaches y==mh-2, x==mw-2
  }  // solve

public void trace()     // override for lab 3/4
    {  // draw a dot (without erasing it) along the OPTIMAL path
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// For part three (save a copy of part 2 version first!), you
// need to implement the KeyListener interface.

public void play() // override for lab 3/4
{
// code to setup game
}
// for this part you may also define some other instance vars outside of
// the play function.

 // skeleton implementation of KeyListener interface
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) // change this one
   {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();       // code for key pressed
        System.out.println("YOU JUST PRESSED KEY "+key);
    }

 } // mazedfs
```

Below is the code:

```
class studentcode extends mazedfs
{
    public studentcode(int bh0, int mh0, int mw0) // don't change constructor
    {
    super(bh0,mh0,mw0);
    }

public void digout(int y, int x)   // modify this function
{
 // The following is a skeleton program that demonstrates the mechanics
 // needed for the completion of the program.

 // We always dig out two spaces at a time: we look two spaces ahead
 // in the direction we're trying to dig out, and if that space has
 // not already been dug out, we dig out that space as well as the
 // intermediate space.  This makes sure that there's always a wall
 // separating adjacent corridors
 //***************************Dig out without recursion*****************
 int[] DX = {0,0,1,-1}; //N,S,E,W
 int[] DY={-1,1,0,0};
 int direction = (int)(Math.random()*4);//creates radnom direction
 coordinate_Stack R = new coordinate_Stack(y, x, direction, null);
 while( R != null)
 {
   y = R.y;
   x = R.x;
   direction = R.dir;
   R = R.next;
   int dx= DX[direction], dy = DY[direction];
   int nx = x+ dx*2;
   int ny = y + dy*2;
   M[y][x]= 1;// dignifies the space as dug out
   drawblock(y,x);//draws on the digout spot 
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     if(nx>=0 && ny>=0 && nx<mw-1 && ny<mh-1 && M[ny][nx]==0)
    {
      drawblock(y+dy, x+dx);
      delay(5);
      direction = (int)(Math.random()*4);
      R = new coordinate_Stack(ny,nx, direction, R);
    }// if
    else
    {
    direction =(1+direction)%4;
    dx = DX[direction];
    dy = DY[direction];
    nx = x + dx*2;
    ny = y+ dy*2;
    R = new coordinate_Stack(ny,nx, direction, R);
    }//else
   }//for
 }//while

}//digout
class coordinate_Stack
{
  int y, x, dir;
  coordinate_Stack next;
  public coordinate_Stack(int a, int b, int f, coordinate_Stack n)
  {y = a; x = b; next = n; dir=f;}
}//coordinate_Stack class
}//studentcode subclass
```

Comment: which is line 32?

Comment: M[y][x]= 1;// dignifies the space as dug out

Comment: where are you initializing M? which are the initial values of x and y?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: digout(mh-2,mw-2); // start digging!

Comment: sorry I will post the full code

Comment: I have now posted the full code

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint in the offending line? Just print out the iteration number let it crash then place the breakpoint and inspect.